# Will Boost.Filesystem handle Windows paths correctly, if it's built using MinGW?

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, boost-filesystem, mingw-w64

Will `Boost.Filesystem` handle Windows paths (*i.e.* backslashes, escapes, etc.) correctly, if the library and the executable are built using MinGW/MinGW-w64, or does it expect Unix paths?

(I don't have a working MinGW installation to test this myself)

Comment: Boost is just source code.  It is built by whatever compiler *you* used.

Comment: Besides, MinGW is a fully native Win32 compiler, it doesn't provide a POSIX compatibility layer like the compiler shipped with cygwin. You shouldn't have any problem.